# Symfony - exporting column names and work with arrays

Tags: php, api, symfony

I am trying to import names of columns that I defined in the varibale $columns and in other rows to export values from db. When I export the file I got all the values from columns but not column names.

```
public function exportCSVAction()
{
    $results = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()
        ->getRepository('ProjectBundle:User')->findAll();

    $columns = '"id","username","email","first_name","last_name","address_one", "city","post_code","mobile","status\n"';

    $response = new StreamedResponse();
    $response->setCallback(function () use ($results) {
        $handle = fopen('php://output', 'r+');
        foreach ($results as $row) {
            $data = array(
                $row->getId(),
                $row->getUsername(),
                $row->getEmail(),
                $row->getFirstName(),
                $row->getLastName(),
                $row->getAddressOne(),
                $row->getCity(),
                $row->getPostCode(),
                $row->getMobile(),
                $row->getStatus(),
            );
            $result = $columns . $data;
            fputcsv($handle, $result);
        }
        fclose($handle);
    });
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/force-download');
    $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="export.csv"');

    return $response;
}
```

I got an error

> expected array got string

and I tried this solution

```
    $toArray = explode(' ', $columns);
    $result = $toArray . ' ' . $data;
    fputcsv($handle, $result);
}
fclose($handle);
```

but it seems its not right solution.

How to get pass this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add `$columns` to every `$data` array, I don't think that this is right solution. Do the following:

```
$handle = fopen('php://output', 'r+');
fputcsv($handle, array(
    "id",
    "username",
    "email",
    "first_name",
    "last_name",
    "address_one", 
    "city",
    "post_code",
    "mobile",
    "status"
));
foreach ($results as $row) {
    fputcsv($handle, array(
        $row->getId(),
        $row->getUsername(),
        $row->getEmail(),
        $row->getFirstName(),
        $row->getLastName(),
        $row->getAddressOne(),
        $row->getCity(),
        $row->getPostCode(),
        $row->getMobile(),
        $row->getStatus(),
    ));
}
fclose($handle);
```